# Python Invalid Syntax error - just getting back into programming

Tags: python

I'm just getting back into coding after a decade long hiatus.  I'm trying to make a word list generator(don't ask me why, it was just a random idea for a project, no mall intent) in python and keep getting this error

/0/qpython/.last_tmp.py && exit File "/storage/emulated/0/qpython/.last_tmp.py", line 25

```
while k<81 and j=0 and h=0 and g=0 and f=0 and e = 0 and d=0 and b=0 and a=0:
```

`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

11:/$
What am I doing wrong?

I'm open to suggestions on a different logic technique

Comment: You mean `==` not `=`. `==` is comparison; `=` is assignment.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting == instead of =. 
= is to assign values to variables. == is to check if a value is equal to another

Comment: I completely forgot about that, thank you!